# Add site-specific custom off-topic reasons to each sites help-center "Avoid asking" or "Close Reasons" page

Tags: feature-request, off-topic, help-center, custom-close-reasons

Just what the title says, each site has it's own custom off topic reasons (or can) as of a feature request from sometime ago, but the Avoid Asking and Close Reasons pages which are not editable by mods and are standard across the help center of each individual SE site only have the standard non-custom close reasons dictating things to avoid asking.

I think it would be good for each site with custom off-topic close reasons to have the full custom close reason's detail added to the Avoid Asking or Close Reasons page for each site in SE so that new users can have somewhere to see those community-chosen close reasons as well as SE's standard ones.

Comment: Weird, I'm sure the help center is editable by mods.

Comment: @Braiam not *all* pages are, at least this is the case of the P.SE mods and the P.SE help center - I can't know if other sites have different perms but I suspect this is just some uniformity SE has placed onto it's sites from on high.

Comment: This needs to be in the "What questions can I ask here" page, since that's likely the only page that most folks are going to read.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for an example; this page is *already* editable by moderators.